# Value error 'dataset' is not one of the example datasets

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, seaborn

Hey so I keep running into this problem where I want to load a dataset to work on it but it doesnt work. the file is CSV file. Two of my files dont work whereas another one of the file does. (Python beginner here)

I was trying to load the dataset but i kept running into errors. attached images. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRxgc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQibp.png) both datasets are located at the same place and both are csv files.

Comment: You can find the example datasets here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, 'elite' is not one of the example datasets.

`sns.load_dataset()` loads one of the example datasets from the internet (see their [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html)).

You can run `sns.get_dataset_names()` to see all available datasets.

If you have an elite.csv file stored locally on your machine, you might wanna try `pandas.read_csv()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Oh thank you for this. I don't know why my teachers overlooked this part. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

```
sns.load_dataset()
```

Loads datasets that are already included in seaborn repositories (using internet connection). You can see the full list using `snsget_dataset_names()`. ([Documentation link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html)).

If you want to import your own CSVs, you can use numpy or pandas.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')
```

Comment: Oh thank you for this. I don't know why my teachers overlooked this part. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider upvoting/accepting if this is the right answer for you.